# Solidity - Is this the correct way to add liquidity to uniswap with exact amount at current price?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, liquidity-provider

I am writing some smart contract code that needs to add liquidity to a Uniswap V2 pair.

I have already performed some validation checks at the start of my transaction function to ensure that the current price is acceptable for providing liquidity.

My contract holds a lot of `Token A` and a small bit of `Token B`.

I would like my contract to use all remaining `Token B` for providing liquidity, along with whatever amount of Token A that is neccessary.

This means I would like to specify an **exact amount** of `Token B`, and let Uniswap calculate how much `Token A` to take away from me.

Is this the correct way to achieve this?

```
uint exactTokenBAmount = _tokenB.balanceOf(address(this));
_tokenA.approve(address(_router), 2 ** 256 - 1);
_tokenB.approve(address(_router), exactTokenBAmount);
_router.addLiquidity(address(_tokenA), address(_tokenB), 0, exactTokenBAmount, 0, exactTokenBAmount, address(this), block.timestamp);
```

As you can see, I am specifying the exact amount for `Token B`, but specifying `0` for `Token A` in the hopes that Uniswap can calculate this amount itself.

Are there any problems with this way of doing it, and if so, is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Well i'm not super familiar with UniswapV2 contracts, so this is just my 2 cents but it seems that router02 calculates that price and checks if it matches what you entered (`uint amountBOptimal = UniswapV2Library.quote(amountADesired, reserveA, reserveB);`), and it indeed seems that uniswapV2Library's `quote` function is what you're looking for

```
    // given some amount of an asset and pair reserves, returns an equivalent amount of the other asset
    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) internal pure returns (uint amountB) {
        require(amountA > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveA > 0 && reserveB > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        amountB = amountA.mul(reserveB) / reserveA;
    }
```

so i would either call it or copy it in my contract (it doesnt make any external calls,you'd just need to call `getReserves` to get `reserveA` and `reserveB` beforehand) to compute this number before calling `addLiquidity`